# Printing Non-English Characters Appears Broken in Node.js Serial Port Printer

Tags: node.js, serial-port, cjk, printers

I'm encountering an issue with a Node.js application that communicates with a serial port printer. When attempting to print non-English characters (such as accented letters or characters from languages like Korean or Chinese, the output appears broken or garbled.
[Print example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpMes.jpg)

Technology Stack: Node.js for application development, utilizing a serial port library for communication with the printer.
Problem: When sending non-English characters to the printer, the output is not rendered correctly and appears broken.
Expected Behavior: The printer should correctly render non-English characters as it does with English characters.
Attempts: I've attempted to encode the characters differently before sending them to the printer using various encoding methods, but none seem to produce the correct output.

Printer model = HMK-830M
Libraries used = serialport (^11.0.0), iconv-lite(^0.6.3)

```
const { SerialPort } = require('serialport');
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');

const port = new SerialPort({
    path: 'COM16',
    baudRate: 19200,
    stopBits: 1,
    parity: 'none',
    autoOpen: false,
    flowControl: false
});

const printWithSerialPort = () => {

    const printContent = async () => {
        var command = '';
        command += '\x1b@' // Reset Printer
        command += '\x1ba\x00' // 80mm paper size
        command += '\x1DL\x1D\x00' // 16mm left margin
        command += '\x1B\x02' // Initial Line Spacing
        command += '\x1b!FS' //COLLECTIVE SETTING OF KOREAN CHARACTER PRINTING_MODE
        command += '\x1b&FS' // SET KOREAN CHARACTER MODE EXTENDED GRAPHIC MODE

        command += iconv.encode('다른 사람들이 사용하기에 도움이 될 것입니다', 'euc-kr');

        command += "\n\n\n\n";
        command += '\x1bi'   // PAPER CUT FULL

        port.write(command, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error on write: ', err.message);
                closePort()
            } else {
                closePort()
            }
        })
    }

    const openPort = () => {
        if (!port.isOpen) {
            port.open((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    return console.error('Error opening port:', err.message);
                }
                console.log('Serial Port Opened');
                printContent();
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Port is already open')
            printContent()
        }
    }

    const closePort = () => {
        if (port.isOpen) {
            port.close((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    return console.error('Error closing port:', err.message);
                }
                console.log('Serial Port Closed');
                port.removeAllListeners('open');
                port.removeAllListeners('data');
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Port is already closed');
        }
    }
    openPort()
}

printWithSerialPort()
```

I'm seeking guidance or insights into how I can properly encode or format non-English characters within Node.js for printing through a serial port, ensuring they are rendered correctly by the printer.

Any help, suggestions, or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.